# Partial views are not loading when hosting the solution on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, deployment, iis-7.5, web-deployment, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I've developed Asp .net MVC3 application.i'm using jquery ajax call for loading parial view.Its working fine when i execute the solution on my local machine.when i deploy the same solution using IIS Partial view not getting loaded.I coudn't find what'll be the issue.Can anyone suggest me some solution on this?

Comment: A possible issue is that you have not included all you javascript files in you solution. If you have not included them they will not be included in you deployment package.

Comment: Open your project, check your scripts folder. if the files are greyed out, right click and select "include in project".